# Function of elements of functions is also a bijection.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am so confused as to how near the bottom it is shown that $h$ is also $1-1$.

If we supposed $h(c) = h(d)$ with $c$ and $d$ of the same parity I understand that.

But how is it shown that whenever $h(c) = h(d)$, $c = d$?

For all I know there could be some $c,d$ with different parity such that $h(c) = h(d)$ and so $h$ is not $1-1$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint, since $B_2$ is defined as having elements which are not in $A_1$. Therefore for any $n$, $h(n)$ is either in $A_1$ or $B_2$ but it's impossible for it to be in both. If $h(n)$ is in $A_1$, then $n$ is odd. If $h(n)$ is in $B_2$, then $n$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose WLOG $c$ is even, $d$ is odd. Then $h(c)=g(c/2)\in B_2$ and $h(d)=f((d+1)/2)\in A_1$. Now since $A_1\cap B_2=\{\},h(c)\ne h(d).$

Answer (score 0):

If $c$ and $d$ have different parity, then one of $h(c)$ and $h(d)$ is in the inmage of $f$, the other in the image of $g$. Since these are $A_1$ and $B_2$ and $A_1\cap B_2 = \emptyset$ by definition of $B_2$, it cannot be true that $h(c) = h(d)$.